# How to Run Command-line main class separately without including existing main-class present in Application in maven based Springboot App?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, junit4, spring-boot-test, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am facing bizarre situation. when i run existing main application it also include another commandLine main-class while running.

I have create 2 profile in **pom.xml**- and also setup mainClass tag.
1- unit-test
2- integration-test

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <mainClass>${commandLineMainClass}</mainClass>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

in integration-test, i have created separate main-class with command-line runner to test the application deployed on another server by just hitting.

i have two issue-

1- when i run **existing main-class application**,  it boot with **command-line mainclass** also. which should be excluded until this is not run manually by command-line.

2. when i run **command line main class**, i m not able to access custom **application-{env}.properties**, although it is not including existing **application main-class** which is good.

I am using **springBoot** maven-plugin also.
please help.

Comment: can you add your full `<build>` section of your `pom.xml` to see the configuration for both profiles and maybe examples on how you run your different use cases

Comment: i have added pom.xml code part in below comment, please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<project>
<parent>
    <groupid>org.springframework.boot</groupid>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>thisisCommandLineProp</start-class>
    <environment>thisisCommandLineProp</environment>
</properties>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>unittest</id>
        <build>
            <filename>${project.artifactId}</filename>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>integrationtest</id>
        <build>
            <filename>${project.artifactId}</filename>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupid>org.springframework.boot</groupid>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <configuration>
                                <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}\src\integration-test\</workingDirectory>
                                <mainClass>${project.basedir}\src\integration-test\${start-class}</mainClass>
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument>
                        spring.config.location=${project.basedir}\src\main\resources\application-${environment}.properties</argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<project>
```

**Command -  ** *spring-boot:run -Denvironment=dev -Dstart-class=com.abc.xyz.Integrationtest -Pintegrationtest*

Comment: i have added pom.xml snippet, please ignore if any typo there.
My Requirement is that, commandline class should work isolated, when i run default application, my integrtion-test commandline class should be ignored. and When i run using commandline, only commmandline class must run and existing default application main-class. must be ignored.

Comment: i am using following command for command line run:
Command -  spring-boot:run -Denvironment=dev -Dstart-class=com.abc.xyz.Integrationtest -Pintegrationtest

Comment: please consider updating your original question next time. There is an _edit_ button